# Indexing a Vector C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am new to Vectors, I think I have a syntactical error, or maybe I'm not calling .at() properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<string> symbols;
std::vector<int> symbolPos;

void addSymbol(string entry, int position){
    for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator i = symbols.begin(); i != symbols.end(); ++i){
        cout << "*i is: " << *i << endl;
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv Problematic line here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    if (symbols.at(i)==entry){
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Problematic line here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            cout << "same entry" << endl;
            break;
        }

        else{
            symbols.push_back(entry);
            symbolPos.push_back(position);
        }
    }
}
```

My compiler is throwing an error, saying that .at() cannot be found. What am I doing wrong here?

```
assembler.cpp: In function ‘void addSymbol(std::string, int)’:
assembler.cpp:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::at(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:650: note: candidates are: typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at(size_t) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:668: note:                 typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::const_reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at(size_t) const [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) expects an argument of type `vector::size_type`, which is typically an alias for `size_t`; this is exactly what the error messages are telling you. You're trying to pass an instance of `vector::iterator` instead.

In your example you already have an iterator to the `vector` element, simply dereference it and do the equality comparison.

```
if (*i==entry)
```

---

You have bigger problems than that though, your entire `for` loop is basically undefined behavior waiting to happen. Say you pass an `entry` to `addSymbol` that doesn't match the first element in `symbols`. Your code causes the `entry` to be `push_back`'d into `symbols`, which will cause `i` to be invalidated if the `vector` need to reallocate storage. The `for` loop then increments `i`, which is undefined behavior. Moreover, do you want to keep iterating over the `vector` once you've added the element to the `vector`?

I think what you want to do is check whether the `vector` contains any element that matches `entry`, and add it if it doesn't exist. To do this, use `find`.

```
if(std::find(symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), entry) == symbols.end()) {
  // entry doesn't exist in the vector
  symbols.push_back(entry);
  symbolPos.push_back(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call at with i, since i is an iterator, so a pointer.like object and you can acces the corresponding value via *i. You can use at with a integer index.

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
if (symbols.at(i)==entry)
```

to

```
if (symbols.at(*i)==entry)
```

Since this function is expecting an integer not a pointer. :)

Comment: It's possible `i` is a pointer (depends on the implementation) but dereferencing it will definitely not yield an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an interator to the symbols vector

```
   if (symbols.at(i)==entry)
```

iterators are not like looping integer variables. so the code must be

```
   if (*i == entry)
```

if you want to use at then replace the for loop with integer value like

```
   for (i = 0; i < symbols.size; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iterators

```
void addSymbol(string entry, int position){

// you can use find function instead of using your own loop
std::vector<string>::iterator i = find(symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), entry);

// if not found
if (i == symbols.end()){
symbols.push_back(entry);
symbolPos.push_back(position);
}
else
cout << "same entry" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method "at" in vector which expects iterator as an input .
It expects size_type parameter . Since you are using an iterator you can simply do strcmp(*i,entry) .
Or another way is to simply switch from using iterator to using operator[] of vector i.e

```
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
   cout<<i<<" th element : "<<v[i]<<endl;
   if(v[i]==entry){
    cout<<"Entry Already Exists"<<endl;
    break;
   }
 }
```

Another very easy way is to use "find" method , by which you can simply search for existence of entry in the present list